# what 'sudo' means for root?

Tags: 14.04, sudo, root

I'm running the following commands in Ubuntu 14.04:

```bsh
root@ubuntu:~# service rpki-ca restart 
stop: Unknown job: rpki-ca
start: Unknown job: rpki-ca
root@ubuntu:~# sudo service rpki-ca restart 
rpki-ca stop/waiting
rpki-ca start/running
root@ubuntu:~#
```

What's the effect of `sudo` in the second command? Why does root need `sudo`?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178980/why-does-the-root-user-need-sudo-permission

Comment: How did you become root? by direct login? I don't think so...

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @muru , it depends on how he became root in the first place.

Comment: @user3073656 indeed. But without that, the question is meaningless.

Comment: @muru exactly, and `man service` says that the environment has a role to play.

Comment: I guess somehow the service is visible only in the `sudo`'s environment scope.

Comment: @muru, I became root by running command 'su', does this matter?

Comment: yes, as @kos's answer clearly shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Googling this, finding this [U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125620/114435), checking its [revisions history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/125620/revisions) and following the quoted source in the [revision #1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/125620/1), this happens to be an [Upstart bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125620/114435); the problem is that when switching to root running `su` the `$UPSTART_SESSION` environment variable is carried from the previous environment instead of being set again.

> After much banging my head and googling, I've found a post (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120050/sudo-service-vsftpd-returns-unknown-job-vsftpd) showing that
>
> `sudo service xxxx start` (or stop, or restart)
>
> works, while
>
> `service xxxx start (in a su session)
>
> does not work.
>
> So the culprit was clearly the environment: If you go root with "su" instead of "sudo su" or "su -", "service" does not to work correctly either, as "su" will carry most of your normal user environment to the root session.
>
> After some testings, I found that the culprit is the UPSTART_SESSION environment variable, which comes set when you "su", but not set when you "sudo su" or "su -". Here are some test results:
>
> -- does not work
>
> ```
> jsveiga@dell:~$ su
> Password:
> root@dell:/home/jsveiga# service smbd restart
> stop: Unknown job: smbd
> start: Unknown job: smbd
> ```
>
> -- works even from a su session
>
> ```
> root@dell:/home/jsveiga# sudo service smbd restart
> smbd stop/waiting
> smbd start/running, process 3823
> ```
>
> -- works
>
> ```
> root@dell:/home/jsveiga# exit
> jsveiga@dell:~$ sudo su
> root@dell:/home/jsveiga# service smbd restart
> smbd stop/waiting
> smbd start/running, process 3862
> ```
>
> -- works
>
> ```
> root@dell:/home/jsveiga# exit
> jsveiga@dell:~$ su -
> Password:
> root@dell:~# service smbd restart
> smbd stop/waiting
> smbd start/running, process 3905
> ```
>
> -- going su then unsetting the UPSTART_SESSION works
>
> ```
> root@dell:/home/jsveiga# exit
> jsveiga@dell:~$ su
> Password:
> root@dell:/home/jsveiga# service smbd restart
> stop: Unknown job: smbd
> start: Unknown job: smbd
> root@dell:/home/jsveiga# unset UPSTART_SESSION
> root@dell:/home/jsveiga# service smbd restart
> smbd stop/waiting
> smbd start/running, process 4244
> ```
>
> So the start/stop scripts are failing somehow simply by the presence of the `UPSTART_SESSION` environment variable.
>
> BR,
>   Joao S Veiga

To fix this, just unset `$UPSTART_SESSION`:

```
unset UPSTART_SESSION
```

or switch to root by other means, like `su -`, `sudo su` or `sudo -i`.

Comment: To *fix* this, always use login shells: `su -` or `sudo -i`.

Answer (score 0):

In that context, it means nothing and should be removed.  Without specifying some other user, `sudo` tries to become root, and so if you are already root, that is a no-op, other than creating an additional process ( for `sudo` itself ) which occupies some resources until the command it is running finishes.

Comment: The problem is that apparently without `sudo` the service won't restart: `root@ubuntu:~# service rpki-ca restart; stop: Unknown job: rpki-ca; start: Unknown job: rpki-ca`